# Unconventional Op-Amp Clipping

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-clipping

I have been scratching my head for a few weeks about the behavior of my circuit (attached). In this circuit I give a arbitrary known input signal to drive a current through R1 which is a thermistor. I then use an instrumentation amplifier to measure across points A and B to calculate the thermistor resistance. Unfortunately when I give the circuit a positive voltage it will clip, but for some reason the negative voltage does not clip. I have looked at the datasheet and confirmed that the opamp can produce the necessary current (\$\pm\$10mA) and I have given sufficient supply voltage (\$\pm\$12V).  I have observed that the clipping does go away with low input voltages i.e. (\$\pm\$1V).  I believe I am missing something trivial but I just can't seem to find it. I have also observed similar behavior with the other ADA4077 opamps in my circuit. I have removed the instrumentation amplifier and isolated the circuit completely and measured the waveforms using an oscilloscope observing the same behavior. I would really appreciate the help guys. Thanks in advance.

The circuit of interest.
[image: Circuit]

Left: The waveform of the input (Yellow) and the voltage measured between A and B (Red). Right: The waveforms of the input and the measured wave at A to ground(Green). The measured waveform at A to my understanding must be really close to zero so this was most intriguing. 
[image]

ADA4077 [DATASHEET](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADA4077-1_4077-2_4077-4.pdf)

Comment: If you replace the "thermistor" with a resistor, is normality restored? (just in case that isn't a thermistor). Also, link to the ADA4077 datasheet in the Q.

Comment: "and the voltage measured between A and B " this sounds a bit confusing, where did you put what clip? the GND clips are internally connected and connected to earth usually, thus if you put GND to A and the probe to B then you measured your signal referring to A not to GND.

Comment: In the datasheet the common mode voltage is not clearly given but where it was mentioned it was not symmetrical e.g. ranging from -3.8 to 3 V. Maybe you are experiencing some problem with that? Especially if you turn down the voltage and the problem goes away.

Comment: Note that A should always be at 0V, and any bias from there will be very small.  You don't need a differential amp.

Comment: @Arsenal -- common mode voltage should not be an issue, as the input terminals should both be at 0V.

Comment: It would seem to me like you made some sort of mistake wiring up your circuit, or you powered it differently from how it is powered in your sim.

Comment: I might expect this result if Vcc was <5V but Vee ok.

Comment: @ScottSeidman ah yeah, messed that up.

Comment: Just a note about your second image. The green curve starts and stops right about the time when the positive-going input reaches the point where it exceeds a diode drop and node A follows upward to a peak of about a diode drop's worth. I'm thinking protection diodes, now. You may need to look into a pin/wiring problem on your device. Can you verify your specific pin choices?

Comment: In your third sentence you mention an instrumentation amplifier. But then you never mention it again and it never appears in your schematics. Can you clarify?

Comment: Is it possible that your scope probe is set on 10x?

Comment: I don't see any bypass caps in your schematic. Do you actually use any?

Comment: 1) Can you just put the probe only on B (to ground), and show us that figure? 2) Are you using a current regulated power supply? What's the maximums current set on each channel? 3) Did you connect the ground to the center tap of the two channels? 4) Can you show us the power rails on the scope? (maybe you got a faulty supply).

Answer (score 1):

The ADA4077 does not let you get very close to the rails -- less than +4 V with a 5V supply.  If your circuit requires an output of  more than about 9.5V, it will not work.  Change R2 to 20K or more.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that your -12V rail isn't holding up, once it hits its own current limit, B can't go any lower so A has to increase.